# onbackpressed not working in kotlin webview

Tags: android, webview, kotlin, onbackpressed

i am working on web view but the app crashes when pressed back button and progress bar does not show 100%
it opens up a website and it also doesnt support javascript alert box?
here is my code

```
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
            view?.loadUrl(url)
            setting!!.domStorageEnabled= true
            setting!!.javaScriptEnabled = true
            return true
        }

    } 
     // Get the web view settings instance
    val settings = webview.settings;
     // Enable java script in web view
    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

    // More optional settings, you can enable it by yourself
    settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true)
    settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
    settings.allowContentAccess = true
    settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        settings.allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true
    }

    settings.allowFileAccess = true

    // WebView settings
    webview.fitsSystemWindows = true

    /* if SDK version is greater of 19 then activate hardware acceleration
    otherwise activate software acceleration  */

    webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)

    webview.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/")

        override fun onBackPressed() {
            if (webview!!.canGoBack()) {
                // If web view have back history, then go to the web view back history
                webview?.goBack()
            }else{
                super.onBackPressed()
            }
        }
```

Logcat had this to say:

```
E/InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.work.social.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.kt:134)
```

Comment: I believe you should show what is at `MainActivity.kt:134` as your logcat says.

Comment: yes its if (webview!!.canGoBack()) { , but couldnt post whole code because stack overflow wont allow it

Answer (score 0):

Remove code from onBackPressed()

Regarding JS alert box, have you tested on real device?

Comment: i removed the onbackpressed code now back button not working

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suspect your local `!!` in `onBackPressed()`.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    when {
        webview?.canGoBack() == true -> webview.goBack()
        else -> super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Calling `!!` is, in most cases, a bad idea. And a source of `KotlinNullPointerException` (eg: Kotlin tries to cast T? as T and if null, fails).

Comment: Post a logcat of the issue.